# Detect hardware acceleration in browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aws-chime-sdk, bodypix

Is there any library or inbuilt javascript using which we can check that the current browser has Hardware Acceleration feature ON or OFF? Right now I'm using Bodypix to set virtual background with chime meeting using react.js which needs hardware acceleration ON for better performance. I just want to give an alert while the user tries to set virtual background with OFF hardware acceleration from their browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript detect if hardware acceleration is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868011/javascript-detect-if-hardware-acceleration-is-enabled)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this package [detect-gpu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-gpu)

Comment: I've tried this but in some system it doesn't detect hardware acceleration is ON/OFF. It doesn't works as expected in FIREFOX too. Because firefox internally uses graphic driver in your system regardless ON/OFF hardware acceleration feature.