# HTML Canvas 2D is too slow

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, gpu

Please help me understand why the process of rendering on an HTML canvas in a 2D context takes so long with several frames falling out of the animation with a large number of points. Moreover, the execution time of the javascript code falls within the allotted 16ms by a large margin, and the main animation time is occupied by the work of the GPU, according to the Performance tab of the developer tools. I will indicate in advance that I am testing on the Google Chrome v122.0.6261.111 browser.

Here is my example code

```js
function main() {
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
    if (!canvas) return

    canvas.width = window.innerWidth
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight

    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    if (!ctx) return

        const length = 20000
    const xStep = canvas.width / length
        const diapason = 50
        const datasetsQty = 7
    const datasets = new Array(datasetsQty).fill(undefined).map((item, index) => {
            const bottom = index * 100
            return generateRandomDataset(length, [bottom, bottom + diapason], xStep)
        })

    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
    ctx.lineWidth = 2

    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        renderer(ctx, datasets)
    })
}

requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    main()
})

/**
* global Y offset
*/
let count = 0

/**
*   build one line per dataset with global Y offset
*/
function renderer(ctx, datasets) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height)
    ctx.beginPath()

    for (let dataset of datasets) {
        for (let i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
            if (!i) ctx.moveTo(dataset[i][0], dataset[i][1] + count)
            else ctx.lineTo(dataset[i][0], dataset[i][1] + count)
        }
    }

    ctx.stroke()
    count++
    count %= window.innerHeight

    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        renderer(ctx, datasets)
    })
}

/**
* generate random dataset in given Y coord range and X is incrementing value
* [[0, random], [1, random], [n, random]...]
*/
function generateRandomDataset(length, range = [0, 50], xStep) {
    const arr = []
    let x = 0

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        arr.push([
            x,
            Math.random() * (range[1] - range[0]) + range[0],
        ])
        x += xStep
    }


    return arr
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/FatBass/f60oznjL/3/) I have visualized the problem. In short, there are several datasets (7 to be specific). In each subsequent frame, I draw all data sets with a Y-axis offset of one pixel below the previous frame.
The code is quite primitive - no matrices or path objects. However, the use of matrices, etc. does not affect the problem - the time it takes to send data for rendering by javascript code is reduced, but the operating time of the GPU has almost no correlation with this fact.

```
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height)
    ctx.beginPath()

    for (let dataset of datasets) {
        for (let i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
            if (!i) ctx.moveTo(dataset[i][0], dataset[i][1] + count)
            else ctx.lineTo(dataset[i][0], dataset[i][1] + count)
        }
    }

    ctx.stroke()
```

I'll give you a few screenshots to help you understand what we're talking about.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWrCh.png) is a performance measurement on the first frame. Please note that the javascript code execution time barely exceeds 1ms, and the GPU loading time is already more than 50ms! Naturally, several animation frames are dropped.
The situation changes as the data sets go beyond the canvas - the execution time of the javascript code does not change, and the GPU load time decreases accordingly. For example, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OPJk.png) is the last frame with one data set on the canvas and the subsequent frames again with all the data sets shown. As you can see, as soon as we have to draw all the data sets in the visible area again, the graphics processor immediately falls under load, again leading to frame drops.

Several facts add interest to the problem:

1. In Mozilla, animation is much smoother without such a colossal load on the GPU.
2. If you reduce the range of Y values ​​without reducing the number of points for a line, then the animation is smoother. (That is, when the depicted data set tends to a straight line in shape)
3. Perhaps such a high GPU load is due to the allocation of the canvas to a separate level, which probably leads to the use of the GPU

The question is essentially contained at the beginning. Why is there such a colossal load on the GPU and how to avoid it?

Thank you in advance, and I really hope that there will be people who can help me figure out raised issue.

Comment: (1) You're probably not using any GPU features with `<canvas>` at all except for the final presentation and compositing. (2) It's browser-dependent, so nothing general. (3/4) On my machine (Chrome 122.0.6261.94 on an Apple Silicon macOS laptop), the Codepen you've linked is perfectly smooth and the performance profiler doesn't exhibit GPU times like yours: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz4JJ.png

Comment: For optimizations, though – (1) if the line itself doesn't change often but the position where you want to draw it might, just draw it onto an image first, and `drawImage()` that cached image where you need it. (2) Don't do an `if` inside the inner loop – moveTo the first point, and just lineTo from points 1..N.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue **in the question itself**, not *just* images and links to external resources. Also please limit your question to a single question.

Comment: AKX, thanks for the answer.

As for the IF block, yes, this is useful advice, but again it will only affect the execution time of the javascript code, not the loading time of the GPU.

Otherwise, the data set is expected to be stretched and compressed along either or both axes at once, so using an image is impractical. I hoped to modify the data set solely by the transformation matrix

Comment: The snippet version is also buttery smooth and shows the same negligible GPU use. Did you try another browser? Are you sure your Chrome is using GPU? (chrome://gpu/)

Comment: AKX, I tried it in three browsers - Chrome, Edge and Mozilla. Acceptable performance only in Mozilla. Moreover, not only on my computer, but also on others. I updated Chrome to the latest version, the problem did not go away.

As for the use of the GPU by Chrome, I don’t quite understand where to look in this tab. As far as I can see, canvas is equipped with hardware acceleration. Only the Vulcan and Skia Graphite fields are disabled

Comment: Well, Chrome and Edge use the same engine, so little wonder. What OS and hardware (CPU, GPU, ...) are you on? Are you using e.g. non-integer scaling in Windows (if you're on Windows)?

Comment: AKX, The environment is:
Windows 10
AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor 3.60 GHz,
NVIDIA GeForce GT 710. 
And non-integer scaling is not used

Comment: You may want to open an issue at https://issues.chromium.org/issues/wizard might be a bug with your GC. I'm also on a mac ARM machine and I also can't repro the issue. When HWA is activated it's super smooth, when disabled the CPU takes all the load and it's a lot slower, but the profiler correctly adds the paint to the CPU. Just to be sure it's not the profiler saying crap, you can try [this little test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868011/javascript-detect-if-hardware-acceleration-is-enabled/77170999#77170999) to ensure your GPU drawing is activated.

Comment: Kaiido, thanks for the reply. Judging by the test, HWA is enabled in all my testing environments.
By the way, an interesting fact: after updating Chrome to the latest version, in some examples such a heavy load on the GPU disappeared, but a painting operation appeared, which lasts as long as the time the GPU was running before.

And yes, I'm thinking about creating a request in chromium

Answer (score 2):

your example looks like this to me:

[image]

but after I set the line width to 1 pixel:
`ctx.lineWidth = 1`
in measuring performance, the load on the GPU has dropped significantly and visually rendering without any lags:

[image]

Comment: It turns out that it is very interesting that increasing the line thickness to 1.1 pixels and to 2 pixels loads the GPU equally in my case. Thank you!